# JavaScriptSerializer to serialize a javascript function name

Tags: asp.net, json, html-helper, javascriptserializer

I am using Flexigrid in my project to add a button on the grid toolbar I can use code like this:

```
...    
"buttons":[
    {"name":"Modifica","bclass":"edit","onpress":"doCommand"},
    {"name":"Elimina","bclass":"delete","onpress":"doCommand"}
],
...
```

Anyway the "onpress" attribute shall contain a reference to a js callback and so this field shall not be enclosed within quotation marks.

I am using the class JavaScriptSerializer (in the System.Web.Script.Serialization namespace) to do the serialization.

How I have to declare the variable to make JavaScriptSerializer serialize like this?

```
...    
"buttons":[
    {"name":"Modifica","bclass":"edit","onpress":doCommand},
    {"name":"Elimina","bclass":"delete","onpress":doCommand}
],
...
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is not a native way to do this with the .NET serializer, but you could execute the following code on the client-side to turn the `onpress` JSON string into a callback...

```
var buttons = []; // Your JSON array
for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  var b = buttons[i];
  b.onpress = window[b.onpress];
}
```

Comment: Is there a need for an eval there ? window[oldOnPress]() should work ?

Comment: You don't need the outer function either.  Just `b.onpress = window[b.onpress];`

Comment: Good! Anyway I did not take this approach because I wanted everything packed inside my HTML helper extension. So I have changed the code in the extension to do something very similar to your suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

How about this trick ?

```
var param = new Dictionary<string,string>();

param["onpress"] = "%doCommand%";

return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize( param ).Replace( "\"%", "" ).Replace( "%\"", "" );
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScriptSerializer is meant for serializing to JSON, and JSON can not represent functions; it also can't refer to previously defined variables.  So I don't believe this is possible.

Comment: Well...you're right. But I have used to build a fluent interface for the grid declaration. There is no way to do this?

Comment: @Lorenzon, there may be a way to get the JavaScript output you want, but not with JavaScriptSerializer alone.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the function name as a string

```
...    
"buttons":[
    {"name":"Modifica","bclass":"edit","onpress":"doCommand"},
    {"name":"Elimina","bclass":"delete","onpress":"doCommand"}
],
...
```

Comment: This is not correct. If you read my question, they're already stored as strings and this does not work because the plugin wants reference to function not function name... ;)